# Importing csv file but few columns are full of special symbols

Tags: r, video, data-cleaning, csv-import

I have imported a movie dataset in csv format, few of the columns are full of special symbols along with the data I need(Example is attached below along with the image of the Movie dataset). Now, do I have to remove those special characters individually OR is there anyway(shortcut) to remove them while importing the file into R. Thanks

[Movie.csv Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEjcd.png)

> **GENRE**
> [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]
>
> **Spoken Languages**
> [{"iso_639_1": "en", "name": "English"}, {"iso_639_1": "es", "name": "Espa\u00f1ol"}]

Comment: You may need to convert using `fromJSON` `library(jsonlite)`

Comment: Facing this error while using fromjson: Error: Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file.

Comment: It is better to show a reproducible example with `dput` and an expected output.  You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more info to create an example so that others can reproduce or test your data

Comment: I'm unclear exactly what your CSV looks like or how you are importing it or what the exact desired result is. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I have tried using dput() but the output is very large to paste here, I have added an image of the dataset in the original question

Comment: Neither of your textual inputs cause an error with `jsonlite::fromJSON`. They are both embedded frames (in R-speak), so you need to be able to deal with a list of frames. If you're using the tidyverse, it deals with nested frames quite well (as does `data.table`, but I don't assume you're using that).

Comment: So you are saying that you have managed to import the data without those special characters in R. Can you please write the commands you used. Thanks @r2evans

Comment: `jsonlite::fromJSON('[{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]')` and `jsonlite::fromJSON(' [{"iso_639_1": "en", "name": "English"}, {"iso_639_1": "es", "name": "Espa\u00f1ol"}]')`

Comment: You can get a list of such frames with something like `lapply(moves$genres, jsonlite::fromJSON)`, assuming no errors. If *some* have errors, you'll need to use `try` or `tryCatch` to get at least some of them. For example `lapply(movies$genres, function(json) tryCatch(jsonlite::fromJSON(json), error=function(e) NA_character))` (untested).

Comment: fromjson is running smoothly when individual rows are entered(as in your 2nd last comment), but it is not working when entire column is provided through lapply, it produces an error"Error: Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file." when used with trycatch the following error is showing: "Error in value[[3L]](cond) : object 'NA_character' not found 1."

Comment: Thanks r2evans, The error was occurring, because the data type of that column was integer and I need to convert the data type from integer to a character. Now your lapply command is working smoothly